# make the modification to another branch in git

Tags: git

I am creating a LBS related android application which need the `MapView`.

However I want to do a  mulitiple implemention. That's to say I want to a app version with `Google MapView` and another app version with `Bing MapView` or something else.

Then I want to separate the `MapView` related operation from the common components in the application.

So I want to use `git` to manage my application.

I do most of the job(the common components not related with `MapView`) in the master branch.

Then I tried to create a new Branch named `google_map` to add the `Google MapView` and a branch named `bing_map` to add the `Bing MapView`. Then I would merge from `master branch` to `google_map` and `bing_map` once I made change for the common components. This will ensure that the `google_map` and `bing_map` branch will always have the same parent.

However when I do the job in the `google_map` I made some modification for the common components which should be done in the master branch.

Then I wonder if I can transfer the change(only the common components) to the master branch. Then I merge the master branch to `google_map` and `bing_map`?

Is this possible?

BTW, the modification I made in the `google_map` branch is not committed yet.

Comment: By the way, I don't think that keeping this code on separate branches is a really good way to manage it. You'll constantly be in danger of making an error during a merge, and if you use git flow, you 'll have to create develop and master branches for both of them. Why not keep the both code versions in one branch and use a simple configuration file to switch between them?

Comment: In fact , the `user` and `product` is used for example, each branch I created represent for a version of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are on the `google_map` branch and the only uncommitted changes are those you want on the `master` branch, all you have to do is:

```
git stash
git checkout master
git stash pop
```

That will leave you on the master branch, with those same changes uncommitted.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try.